# Como formatar uma string para adicionar espaços à direita numa tabela impressa?

Tags: java, formatação

Estou tentando imprimir uma tabela em Java, utilizando o método `System.out.format`, onde a saída deve ficar desse jeito:

```
(Dados apenas de exemplo. Não são reais.)

SBGR -> BCO   | 9,0 m     | 5,0 NM   | 1400 Ft/m | 700
BCO  -> GHK   | 15,5 m    | 67,0 NM  | 2000 Ft/m | 2130
GHK  -> NIBIL | 11,7 m    | 125,0 NM | 700 Ft/m  | 3700
```

O código que estou utilizando no momento é esse:

```
String format = "%s -> %6s | %4.1f m | %5.1f NM | %6d Ft/m | %6d\n";
System.out.format(format, origin, destination, estimatedTime, distance, verticalSpeed, estimatedFuel);
```

Eu sei que o código atual, para o que eu busco, está errado porque o número de espaços está à esquerda do ponto, na string de formatação. Porém, se eu colocasse o número de espaços à direita do ponto, eu teria números ao invés de espaços em branco.

Minha dúvida é: qual a formatação para adicionar espaços em branco à direita do valor, seja uma string ou um número?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na [documentação de `format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) há um link para a página ["Format String Syntax"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), que descreve todas as opções possíveis. Lá podemos encontrar esta tabela:

| Flag | General | Character | Integral | Floating Point | Date/Time | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '-' | y | y | y | y | y | **The result will be left-justified** |
| '#' | y | - | y | y | - | The result should use a conversion-dependent alternate form |
| '+' | - | - | y | y | - | The result will always include a sign |
| ' ' | - | - | y | y | - | The result will include a leading space for positive values |
| '0' | - | - | y | y | - | The result will be zero-padded |
| ',' | - | - | y | y | - | The result will include locale-specific grouping separators |
| '(' | - | - | y | y | - | The result will enclose negative numbers in parentheses |

Ou seja, para alinhar à esquerda, bastaria usar o hífen no formato: `%-4.1f` em vez de `%4.1f`, por exemplo. O problema é que isso só formata o número, mas você quer formatar também a unidade de medida junto, **então somente isso não funcionaria**:

```
String origin = "SGBR", destination = "BCO";
double estimatedTime = 9, distance = 5;
int verticalSpeed = 1400, estimatedFuel = 700;
String format = "%s -> %6s | %-4.1f m | %-5.1f NM | %-6d Ft/m | %-6d\n";
System.out.format(format, origin, destination, estimatedTime, distance, verticalSpeed, estimatedFuel);
```

A saída seria:

```
SGBR ->    BCO | 9.0  m | 5.0   NM | 1400   Ft/m | 700
```

Repare que somente os números foram alinhados à esquerda, então ficou `5.0   NM` em vez de `5.0 NM` e mais os espaços depois dele (vale notar também que o separador decimal varia conforme o *locale default* da JVM, mas já chegaremos lá).

---

Enfim, no seu caso, você não quer formatar somente o número, e sim o número seguido da unidade de medida, e já formatado com a vírgula separando as casas decimais. Ou seja, você quer formatar uma string alinhada à esquerda (sendo que esta string é formada por um número e mais a unidade de medida).

Então eu sugiro primeiro formatar os números junto com a unidade de medida, gerando as respectivas strings, e depois formate estas strings alinhando à esquerda.

Algo assim:

```
// junta o número com a unidade de medida
// o locale é para controlar o separador decimal
static String formataNumero(double valor, String unidade, int casasDecimais, Locale locale) {
    if (unidade.isEmpty()) { // sem unidade, formata só o número
        return String.format(locale, "%." + casasDecimais + "f", valor);
    }
    // com unidade, junta com o número
    return String.format(locale, "%." + casasDecimais + "f %s", valor, unidade);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String origin = "SGBR", destination = "BCO";
    double estimatedTime = 9, distance = 5;
    int verticalSpeed = 1400, estimatedFuel = 700;
    Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "BR"); // para usar a vírgula como separador decimal

    String format = "%-4s -> %-6s| %-9s | %-8s | %-9s | %s\n";
    System.out.format(format, origin, destination,
            formataNumero(estimatedTime, "m", 1, locale),
            formataNumero(distance, "NM", 1, locale),
            formataNumero(verticalSpeed, "Ft/m", 0, locale), // inteiros usam zero casas decimais
            formataNumero(estimatedFuel, "", 0, locale));
}
```

Usei um `Locale` para que o separador decimal seja a vírgula (usei "pt-BR", que equivale ao português brasileiro). Se você não especificar um, ele usará o *locale default* que estiver configurado na JVM, e nem sempre pode ser o que você precisa (por exemplo, se for inglês, o separador será o ponto). Além disso, o *locale default* pode ser alterado em *runtime* por qualquer aplicação rodando na mesma JVM, e você não tem muito controle sobre isso. Então é melhor usar um *locale* específico.

Assim, eu só preciso formatar strings. Ajustei os tamanhos para ficar igual à sua saída desejada:

```
SGBR -> BCO   | 9,0 m     | 5,0 NM   | 1400 Ft/m | 700
```

Mas aí você pode ajustar para o que precisar. Repare que o último número não precisa ser alinhado à esquerda, já que não há nada depois dele. Se você usasse algo como `%-6s`, ficariam alguns espaços em branco no final, mas como é a última informação da linha, não achei necessário.