# Como formatar um número double para N decimais sem arredondar?

Tags: java, formatação, double

Eu tenho um valor do tipo `double` e gostaria de formatá-lo para que fique com 3 decimais apenas, **sem arredondamento**. Para isso, eu estou tentando utilizar o `String.format` da seguinte maneira:

```
float value = Float.parseFloat(String.format("%.3f", myDoubleValue));
```

O problema é que quando eu executo esse código, o seguinte erro é gerado:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-23,319"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Existe uma maneira "ideal" para realizar essa formatação? Sei que existem outras formas de se formatar os decimais — como o `DecimalFormat` — porém elas arredondam o número, e não é isso o que eu desejo.

Detalhe: para esse projeto, eu preciso do máximo de otimização possível. Então eu gostaria de uma solução "leve" para formatar o número.

Comment: Você quer gerar uma string ou um `float` com as 3 primeiras casas decimais? Apesar de parecer, não é a mesma coisa, porque "formatar" geralmente quer dizer "transformar em string", podendo mudar o separador decimal e dos milhares, etc. Inclusive, esse foi o erro: `String.format` usa o locale default da JVM, que no seu caso é um que usa a vírgula (já expliquei isso [na sua outra pergunta](/q/510792/112052)), e `parseFloat` só reconhece o ponto.

Comment: De qualquer forma, `Decimalformat` tem a [opção de mudar a forma de arredondamento](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode)), teste aí (acho que é o `DOWN`, mas veja aí). Mas se quiser um `float`, acho mais fácil fazer a conta mesmo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/459884/112052 (essa é em JavaScript, mas a ideia é a mesma)

Comment: De qualquer forma 2: `String.format` arredonda sim :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *elas arredondam o número, e não é isso o que eu desejo*

Bom, `String.format` também arredonda:

```
// quarta casa decimal é >= 5, arredonda para cima
System.out.println(String.format("%.3f", 1.2225)); // 1,223

// quarta casa decimal é < 5, arredonda para baixo
System.out.println(String.format("%.3f", 1.2224)); // 1,222
```

Creio que quando você diz "não arredondar", quer dizer que o resultado deveria ser `1,222` para ambos os casos, certo?

Vale lembrar que o separador decimal poderá ser a vírgula ou o ponto, dependendo do *locale default* da JVM, conforme já explicado [em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/510792/112052). Mas quando você usa `String.format`, o arredondamento sempre é feito, inclusive isso é dito na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec):

> *the value will be rounded using the round half up algorithm*

E o tal algoritmo de arredondamento citado é descrito [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP).

---

De qualquer forma, o que exatamente você quer fazer?

**Se você quer obter um `float` somente com as 3 primeiras casas decimais**, aí só precisa usar a boa e velha matemática:

```
// manter apenas as N primeiras casas decimais
static float manterCasas(float valor, int qtdCasas) {
    float fator = (float) Math.pow(10, qtdCasas);
    return (float) (Math.floor(valor * fator) / fator);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // sempre mantém as 3 primeiras casas, sem arredondar
    System.out.println(manterCasas(1.2225f, 3)); // 1.222
    System.out.println(manterCasas(1.2224f, 3)); // 1.222
}
```

A ideia para manter as N primeiras casas é multiplicar o número por 10<sup>N</sup>, arredondar para baixo e em seguida dividir por 10<sup>N</sup> (conforme já explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/459884/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252253/112052)).

---

**Mas se você quer uma `String`** com as 3 primeiras casas decimais, controlando inclusive o separador decimal, aí pode usar `DecimalFormat` mesmo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(formatar(1.2225f, 3)); // 1.222
    System.out.println(formatar(1.2224f, 3)); // 1.222
}

static String formatar(float valor, int qtdCasas) {
    NumberFormat fmt = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance();
    // limitar quantidade de casas decimais
    fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(qtdCasas);
    // arredondar para baixo tem o mesmo efeito que "não arredondar a última casa decimal"
    fmt.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
    return fmt.format(valor);
}
```

Lembrando que o separador decimal pode ser o ponto ou a vírgula, de acordo com o *locale default* da JVM. Se quiser um específico, pode passar o *locale* para o `NumberFormat`. Ex:

```
// usar locale pt-BR (português do Brasil) para o separador decimal ser a vírgula
NumberFormat fmt = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
```

Lembrando que por padrão o separador de milhares também é colocado (`1000` é formatado como `1.000`). Se quiser desabilitar isso, faça `fmt.setGroupingUsed(false);`.

Outro detalhe é que se o número tiver menos que 3 casas decimais, não serão mostradas todas. Se quiser que sempre seja mostrado 3, basta adicionar `fmt.setMinimumFractionDigits(qtdCasas);`.

---

Por fim, vale lembrar de não confundir um número com a sua representação. Um número como `1,5` é apenas um valor... numérico que não possui formato em si (é só um conceito, uma ideia: ele representa um determinado valor, só isso). Mas este mesmo número pode ser representado de várias formas: como `1.5`, `1,5`, `um e meio`, `000001.500`, etc.

Ou seja, um valor numérico guardado em um `float` (ou `int`, ou `double`, etc) não tem formato, mas ele pode ser convertido para uma string que representa este valor de diferentes formas. Quando eu imprimo o número, ele é convertido para uma string em determinado formato (com `println`, por exemplo, eu não controlo o formato, mas com `format` e `DecimalFormat` sim). Então é importante saber o que você precisa: mudar o valor numérico (gerar outro `float` somente com as 3 primeiras casas decimais) ou apenas gerar uma string que representa o número com as 3 primeiras casas.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o NumberFormat

```
   Double variavel_qualquer = 5.5641;
   NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");     
   System.out.println(formatter.format(4.0));
   System.out.println(formatter.format(variavel_qualquer));
```

Resposta:

4.00

5.56